# Hibernate - SuperClass -MappedSuperClass

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, relationship, mappedsuperclass

How can I provide a relationship between two derived class from the same class on hibernate.

I have a class named BaseEntity and it has some attributes that every derived class will have too, such as updateDate,updateID.

And I have two classes derived from that BaseClass named Salary and Employee. And those classes must have a relationship between them which is one-to-one. How can I accomplish that? I have been reading about Hibernate but I haven't seen anything related to this, or I am thinking in a totally wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple.You can declare a salary variable in Employee class and annotate it with `@OneToOne` annotation.

```
 @OneToOne
 private Salary salary;
```